# Blog search in SQL adding the tags in the search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, full-text-search

I have 3 tables for my blogs/tags

lm_blog, lm_blog_tags, and lm_blog_tag_relationships.

I am now trying to add a search feature that uses Boolean searching. I got that ok but I cant get it to search the tags as well.

```sql
SELECT blog.blog_id, title, url, summary, 
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag SEPARATOR ':') AS tags, 
MATCH(title) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS title_rel, 
MATCH(summary) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS summary_rel, 
MATCH(article) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS article_rel 
FROM lm_blog AS blog
INNER JOIN lm_blog_tag_relationships AS rel 
ON blog.blog_id = rel.blog_id 
INNER JOIN lm_blog_tags AS tags 
ON rel.tag_id = tags.tag_id
WHERE MATCH(title, summary, article) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY blog.blog_id 
ORDER BY title_rel DESC, summary_rel DESC, article_rel DESC, blog.updated DESC
```

I have tried adding another `WHERE` clause to match against the aggregate tags but you cant use group data in a where clause. As far as I am aware there isn't a way to do a `WHERE OR HAVING` either...

Heres the closest I have gotten but it checks WHERE and HAVING. I need a WHERE or HAVING

```sql
SELECT blog.blog_id, title, url, summary, 
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag SEPARATOR ':') AS tags, 
MATCH(title) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS title_rel, 
MATCH(summary) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS summary_rel, 
MATCH(article) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS article_rel 
FROM lm_blog AS blog
INNER JOIN lm_blog_tag_relationships AS rel 
ON blog.blog_id = rel.blog_id 
INNER JOIN lm_blog_tags AS tags 
ON rel.tag_id = tags.tag_id
WHERE MATCH(title, summary, article) AGAINST($query IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY blog.blog_id 
HAVING tags LIKE $query 
ORDER BY title_rel DESC, summary_rel DESC, article_rel DESC, blog.updated DESC
```

Comment: use HAVING.  It takes place after the group/aggregate functions.

Comment: Is there a way to do a WHERE OR HAVING. my understanding is you cant. I need it to be in the full text search (WHERE) or a tag (HAVING).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after a few hours of searching...It's actually easy. Just select one with tags and select one with full text searching and join them with a UNION DISTINCT.

```
SELECT blog.blog_id, title, url, summary, updated, 
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag SEPARATOR ':') AS tags, 
MATCH(title) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS title_rel, 
MATCH(summary) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS summary_rel, 
MATCH(article) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS article_rel 
FROM lm_blog AS blog
INNER JOIN lm_blog_tag_relationships AS rel 
ON blog.blog_id = rel.blog_id 
INNER JOIN lm_blog_tags AS tags 
ON rel.tag_id = tags.tag_id
WHERE MATCH(title, summary, article) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
GROUP BY blog.blog_id 

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT blog.blog_id, title, url, summary, updated, 
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag SEPARATOR ':') AS tags,  
MATCH(title) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS title_rel, 
MATCH(summary) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS summary_rel, 
MATCH(article) AGAINST ($query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS article_rel 
FROM lm_blog AS blog
INNER JOIN lm_blog_tag_relationships AS rel 
ON blog.blog_id = rel.blog_id 
INNER JOIN lm_blog_tags AS tags 
ON rel.tag_id = tags.tag_id
GROUP BY blog.blog_id 
HAVING tags REGEXP $query

ORDER BY title_rel DESC, summary_rel DESC, article_rel DESC, updated DESC
```

It doesn't look like I can use `HAVING ... MATCH ... AGAINST ...` so I will just use a regexp for this until i find a solution.